# Tridion - Commiting Deployment Failed (TransientObjectException)

Tags: tridion

I'm trying to publish a page in Tridion and keep getting the following NHibernate exception in the "Committing Deployment" phase:

> Retried 10 times to commit and failed,
>   org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved
>   transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:
>   com.tridion.storage.BinaryVariant.binaryMeta ->
>   com.tridion.storage.BinaryMeta,
>   org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved
>   transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:
>   com.tridion.storage.BinaryVariant.binaryMeta ->
>   com.tridion.storage.BinaryMeta

The page looks fine if I preview it in Template Builder, can anyone provide any info on why this might be happening?

**Update**

To clarify, this isn't caused by binary conflicts - A TBB takes care of those and there aren't even any binaries on the page. It looks like a Broker database issue, as publishing a copy of the page works fine.

Comment: Component presentations linking to binaries will sometimes render correctly in Template Builder or "Preview" but not publish because of conflicting binaries. Typically the same variant is published to different locations by different templates (must be different) or different templates publish the same binary to the same location with different variant ids (must be the same). But this typically results in a "binary already published" type error rather than that stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had similar issues, and found it to be something gone wrong in the Broker DB, generally un-publishing the page and re-publishing it has solved the issue. Not a great solution I know, but has worked for us